# Building Oatpp app in Docker failure to build due to threads

Tags: docker, cmake

I am trying to build my application that uses the Oatpp library within a docker container, but I keep getting this error:

```
#7 3.638 oatpp version: '1.3.0'
#7 3.647 -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
#7 3.669 -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
#7 3.669 -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
#7 3.695 -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
#7 3.695 -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
#7 3.719 -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
#7 3.719 -- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
#7 3.742 -- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - no
#7 3.743 CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
#7 3.743   Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)
#7 3.743 Call Stack (most recent call first):
#7 3.743   /usr/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
#7 3.743   /usr/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:228 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
#7 3.743   src/CMakeLists.txt:311 (find_package)
```

Google has shown other people have had issues, which is why I have included the libpthread-stubs0-dev library.

The docker file is listed below and is run using 'docker build --file Dockerfile.proto .'

```
from ubuntu:23.04

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    apt update && \
    apt-get install --yes git && \
    apt-get install --yes cmake && \
    apt-get install --yes build-essential && \
    apt-get install --yes libpthread-stubs0-dev

RUN git clone https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp.git && \
    cd oatpp && \
    mkdir build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake .. && \
    make install
```